# php how to foreach to create a case on switch

Tags: jquery, loops, foreach, switch-statement

I have created a little logic when the user choose the radio...

http://jsfiddle.net/ZVuGz/

when the user choose... the data will get the price to calculate...

but my question is what if I had a multiple query result? for example 8

I will make a loop to count how many result then foreach all that and make them into CASES on the query..

like

```
case '1':
    $('#show').html("1st radio button");
    break;
case '2':
    $('#show').html("2nd radio button");
    break;
```

and just loop this until `case '8':`

does it posible on php? or does any other solution?

Comment: You're mixing PHP with JS; `$result="No Love";`

Comment: aw I mean on JS... how to do that?